# How to set a 404 page in nginx with prerender included

Tags: nginx, prerender

I currently have a Nginx server with prerender working. But for some reason when a resource is not found it is redirected to the index.html page instead of displaying a 404.

Here is my config, any help would be appreciated.

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name localhost;

root /home/administrator/public_html;
index  index.html;

location / {
    try_files $uri @prerender;
}

location @prerender {
    error_page 404 = @normal;

    #proxy_set_header X-Prerender-Token TOKEN;

    set $prerender 0;
    if ($http_user_agent ~* "baiduspider|twitterbot|facebookexternalhit|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora link preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator") {
        set $prerender 1;
    }
    if ($args ~ "_escaped_fragment_") {
        set $prerender 1;
    }
    if ($http_user_agent ~ "Prerender") {
        set $prerender 0;
    }
    if ($uri ~ "\.(js|css|xml|less|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|pdf|doc|txt|ico|rss|zip|mp3|rar|exe|wmv|doc|avi|ppt|mpg|mpeg|tif|wav|mov|psd|ai|xls|mp4|m4a|swf|dat|dmg|iso|flv|m4v|torrent|ttf|woff)") {
        set $prerender 0;
    }

    #resolve using Google's DNS server to force DNS resolution and prevent caching of IPs
    resolver 8.8.8.8;

    if ($prerender = 1) {

        #setting prerender as a variable forces DNS resolution since nginx caches IPs and doesnt play well with load balancing
        set $prerender "service.prerender.io";
        rewrite .* /$scheme://$host$request_uri? break;
        proxy_pass http://$prerender;
    }
}
location @normal {
}
}
```

I updated the question with a working config with the help of @JuniorCompressor

Comment: I figured out with the help of @JuniorCompressor to get it working.
I updated the question with a working config.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
server {
   ...
   location @prerender {
      recursive_error_pages on;
      error_page 404 = @normal;
      ...
      if ($prerender = 0) {
          return 404;
      }
      ...
   }

   location @normal {
   }
}
```

You let `@prerender` throw a not found and then `@normal` can handle normally the request.

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name localhost;

root /home/administrator/public_html;
index  index.html;

location / {
    try_files $uri @prerender;
}

location @prerender {
    error_page 404 = @normal;

    #proxy_set_header X-Prerender-Token TOKEN;

    set $prerender 0;
    if ($http_user_agent ~* "baiduspider|twitterbot|facebookexternalhit|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora link preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator") {
        set $prerender 1;
    }
    if ($args ~ "_escaped_fragment_") {
        set $prerender 1;
    }
    if ($http_user_agent ~ "Prerender") {
        set $prerender 0;
    }
    if ($uri ~ "\.(js|css|xml|less|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|pdf|doc|txt|ico|rss|zip|mp3|rar|exe|wmv|doc|avi|ppt|mpg|mpeg|tif|wav|mov|psd|ai|xls|mp4|m4a|swf|dat|dmg|iso|flv|m4v|torrent|ttf|woff)") {
        set $prerender 0;
    }

    #resolve using Google's DNS server to force DNS resolution and prevent caching of IPs
    resolver 8.8.8.8;

    if ($prerender = 1) {

        #setting prerender as a variable forces DNS resolution since nginx caches IPs and doesnt play well with load balancing
        set $prerender "service.prerender.io";
        rewrite .* /$scheme://$host$request_uri? break;
        proxy_pass http://$prerender;
    }
}

location @normal {
}
```

}

Tnx to @JuniorCompressor